# WFFM Selecting a List Item doesn't work

Tags: wffm

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 with WFFM Version 170518. I'm trying setup a dropdown list that has country codes as values and names as display. Here's what my setup looks like:
[image: List of Sitecore items]

When I click on the Dropdown arrow next to the **Value** caption, I get my dropdown list
[image: Arrow Highlighted]

I select the **Country Code** option from the list, but nothing changes, and I don't get the Country Code from my form.

[image: Country Code Selection]

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

I got a response back from Sitecore support on this issue, and apparently this is a known bug for the particular version of Sitecore and WFFM that I'm using. So if you encounter this, ask Sitecore Support for the appropriate patch file.

The support reference number to ask Sitecore about is **133319**.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else getting here because of the same or similar issue with a list item and "Selecting Sitecore item"-query not working correctly in WFFM, here is the "raw value" to use in a list item's `Localized Parameters`-field for custom `Value:` and `Text:` field references:

```
<Items>%3cquery+t%3d%22root%22+vf%3d%22FIELDNAME-FOR-VALUE%22+tf%3d%22FIELDNAME-FOR-TEXT%22%3e%3cvalue%3e%7bROOT-ITEM-ID%7d%3c%2fvalue%3e%3c%2fquery%3e</Items>
```

For example, referring to the original question here, the following raw value string would work as `Localized Parameters`:

```
<Items>%3cquery+t%3d%22root%22+vf%3d%22Country%20Code%22+tf%3d%22__Item%20Name%22%3e%3cvalue%3e%7b99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999%7d%3c%2fvalue%3e%3c%2fquery%3e</Items>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not used WFFM 8.2 but this kind of setup (custom dropdown lists using items as sources) works fine for us in WFFM 8.1, so I can't see why it wouldn't in this version unless there is a bug or something up with the setup.

If your custom country items have codes in the country code field and they are still coming back empty one way to solve this would be to use something like Sitecore Powershell to set the displayname of the items to the county name and the name of the items to the country code. You can then select __name as the value and __display name as the text to show in WFFM. Perhaps not ideal but this should work if there is a bug or you need a quicker solution.